# Why I cannot log in to the SQL Server (Error 18456)

Tags: sql-server

I recently installed SQL Server 2017 but I was not able to log into through SSMS. It always shows this error Message:

[image: SQL Server Error]

I already checked the TCP, the Port 1433 and the Firewall. It must be something else. I already reinstalled it some times and tried some other versions.

This is the followin log it created if I try to log into the SQL Server:

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5. Logon
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-DJL8SSV\Athavan'. Reason: 
Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Could you help me out with that.

Comment: When you install SQL Server, you enter a password for "sa".  Log in with that first.  Then you can add permissions for whatever user you want to login.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I cannot enter with "sa". And why does Windows-Authentication doesn't work?

Comment: When you install SQL Server, you can specify the Windows accounts to be provisioned as sysadmin role members during setup. Did you do that?

Comment: Did you have some error messages during installation? I had similar error and ended up with Windows Fresh Start (win 10) and re-installation of all soft (starting from sql server 2016 and 2017).

Comment: not that I know of

Comment: If you didn't specify the users that are a `sysadmin` and you didn't specify a password for the `sa` login, what did you do? Might be time to uninstall and try again, making sure you read each of the prompts carefully.

Comment: Usually the account used to install SQL Server is automatically added as a sysadmin and cannot be removed during installation. You probably have switched to a privileged user for the installation (some administrator account)? If yes, use this account. (Adding or providing a password for the `sa` SQL Server account or other Windows accounts is optional though, if you didn't do it you cannot use it until you changed the settings later.)

Comment: did you perform an upgrade to the current instance or created a new instance ?